# Error when masking 2d numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, valueerror

I'm not sure what the correct terminology is here but I'm trying to mask out some values in a numpy array using multiple conditions from several arrays. For example, I want to find and mask out the areas in X where arrays t/l,lat2d,x, and m meet certain criteria. All the arrays are of the same shape: (250,500). I tried this:

```
cs[t < 274.0 | 
   l > 800.0 |
   lat2d > 60 |
   lat2d < -60 | 
   (x > 0 & m > 0.8) |
   (x < -25 & m < 0.2)] = np.nan
```

ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.

I replaced the &,| with and/or and got the error:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I've tried creating a mask: mask = t < 274.0 | l > 800.0 | lat2d > 60 | lat2d < -60 | (x > 0 & m > 0.8) | (x < -25 & m < 0.2), in order to use in a masked array but got the same error.

any idea how to do this in Python 3?

Comment: are the arrays `l, t, m, x, lat2d` fixed?

Comment: Yes, the arrays are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a matter of operator precedence:

```
cs[(t < 274.0) | 
   (l > 800.0) |
   (lat2d > 60) |
   (lat2d < -60) |
   ((x > 0) & (m > 0.8)) |
   ((x < -25) & (m < 0.2))] = np.nan
```

should work

Comment: This is pretty neat!

Comment: So the parenthesis were the issue? Can you explain a bit more how your () are different than mine?

Comment: @Shejo284 I think it boils down to remembering the precedence rule `PEMDAS` in that order. So, using parenthesis will always make thing explicit and of higher precedence (i.e. it evaluates first)

Comment: The problem is that for certain technical reasons numpy abuses bitwise operators where in an ideal world logical operators would be used. These bitwise operators have higher operator precedence than their logical cousins, so for example without the additional parentheses your condition is interpreted like t < (274.0 | l) > (800.0 | ... which, of course, doesn't make much sense. For starters bitwise `or` is not defined on floats.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I see. Thanks for the solution and explanation. I'm a bit wiser today, pun intended :-)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence; precedence is `&,<,and`.  `ndarray` overloads `&` and `<` to work `elementwise`,but leaves `and` as a python `scalar` boolean operation..

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using with a python function and then applying that function on the array.

```
def cond(x):
    if (np.all(t < 274.0) or np.all(l > 800.0) or np.all(lat2d > 60) or \
        np.all(lat2d < -60) or (np.all(x > 0) and np.all(m > 0.8)) or  \
        (np.all(x < -25) and np.all(m < 0.2))):
        return np.nan
```

Then apply this function on the array:

```
cs[:] = np.apply_along_axis(cond, 0, cs)
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but the other suggested solution works and with less coding. Appreciate the tips though :-)